# php exec java error java not found

Tags: php

Everybody who can use a command php `exec` to run a java. I have a problem on my coding to testing java.

```
$output = exec("java -version 2>&1");
echo $output;
```

When I run a script on web browser I found,

> java: not found

How can I work with php exec java.
P.S. I could run a command `php java -version` on a shell command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error says, java is not installed on the system or the path is not set

Comment: I doubt you can run `php java -version` in cli

Answer (score 2):

As the error is saying, java is probably not installed on your system. You didn't specify an operating system but here is the output of `java -version` in ubuntu without java:

```
x@y:~$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

As you can see it even tells you how to install java, the package I would suppose you need is `default-jre` so you can go ahead and run `sudo apt-get install default-jre`.

As to being able to run `php java -version` that means you have a file named `java` in the current working directory which runs php (for some reason?).

Of course you will have to research how to install java on your type of operating system, google is your friend here.

Comment: Problem was resolved. I put a full path /usr/local/jdk1.6.0/jre/bin/java in a php script.